# WSO2 ESB and GReg on same Carbon instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I have installed WSO2 AS, after I have installed GReg and ESB by Feature Install. It was OK.

But now I would like to know how to I have to configure GReg and ESB using same WSO2 Application Server.

For example, I would like to configure ESB and GReg following pattern #2 or pattern #3 of [this blog post](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances)  but considering that ESB and GReg were installed in same WSO2 AS instance.

Is that a correct escenary ? or I Have to install allways in separated AS ?

Regards!

Oscar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These patterns are used when you need to share registry spaces across multiple server instances. A common config registry space is used to share configuration details across multiple instances of the same product. A common governance registry space is used to share metadata across the multiple products in a platform.

In the setup you have described,since ESB and AS products are installed in the same server, there is no need for sharing the registry space.

Sharing the registry space would be required only if these products are run as separate server instances.

Is there any particular reason/requirement you have for the setup described?

Regards,
Gillian

Comment: Hi Gillian, 
Thanks so much for your answer. The idea is to implement in the same AS to create an architecture as the one shown upper. Do you think this can be done?

Thanks & Regards,
Oscar

Comment: Hi Oscar,
Recommended approach would be move the G-Reg out of the AS+ESB servers. Registry space between the 2 server instance can then be shared using a remote G-Reg instance. Refer http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS501/Sharing+Registry+Space+Among+Multiple+Products for details on this.

Further, it is also recommended that you use the internal registry space for each server's local registry. So there is no need to use an external G-reg for the local registry space.

Hope this clarifies. Cheer, Gillian